# How to fix snap on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, apparmor, snap

I have a problem with snap. For example when I try to run firefox I have this error :

```
pc:~$ firefox
cannot open /tmp/snap-private-tmp: Permission denied
```

When I look the log I have :

```
kernel: audit: type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=16346 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"

kernel: audit: type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap-private-tmp/" pid=16346 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

What needs to be done to make firefox run and fix snap?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this post https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/apparmor-rejecting-fsetid-for-snap-confine/1386

Comment: Also, a better place to ask this would be https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: CootMoon, thanks, I saw the link but it doesn't say how to fix it

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar with secrets password manager. In the end it was the ~/snap/secrets/ folder permissions (group set to rw) that needed adjusting.

Comment: Need what adjusting? To add write access or to remove it?